# CSS event hover for bigger picture

Tags: css

I try to make image gallery using bootstrap and my custom CSS. I want to make if the user hover on the image, the picture will getting bigger on its place. Everything is done by only using css but I have a little problem regarding the grid of my image. When I hover the most right image, the position will be mess. Here is my experiment : http://hanzoclothing.com/lookbook/chapter-iii

CSS:

```
.lookbook-item{
    position: relative !important;
}
.lookbook-item:hover{
    z-index: 5;
}
.lookbook-item .thumb{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.lookbook-item .thumb img{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.lookbook-item .thumb:hover img{
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: -50px;
/*    top: 200%;
    left: 23%;*/
    z-index: 6;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use `transform: scale(xxx);` for this. It will do exactly what you want without effecting other elements:

```
.lookbook-item .thumb:hover img {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* min-width: 600px; */
    /* max-width: 600px; */
    /* margin-top: -40px; */
    /* margin-left: -50px; */
    z-index: 6;
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

If you want to keep the offset you currently have, you could use the following:

`transform: scale(2) translate(50px, 40px);`